# discover snmp oid with low-level discovery in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, snmp, zabbix

I have 10 Cisco Switches (model 3750) with different updates of IOs. I want to know is there a way to use low-level discovery to automatically add my desired MIBs to zabbbix? for example to monitor the traffic of port1 I need to get the value of IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10001. Without using low-level, I should define 48 items for each switch (because due to different OS updates they use different OIDs). I want to have a low-level discovery or something like that to add all OIDs to my host (IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10001,IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10002,IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10003,...).
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that's exactly what the [SNMP LLD](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#discovery_of_snmp_oids) is for.
Even more, there's a default template "Template SNMP Interfaces", which will do that for you out of the box. If you have lost it somehow, you can always get a fresh copy here: http://zabbix.org/mw/images/0/02/Template_SNMP_Interfaces-2.0.0.xml .

Comment: WoW. Thank you @Richlv. That's exactly what I need. But I should work a little around it to make my desired rules.